# api platform - Unable to generate an IRI for the item

Tags: php, rest, symfony, api-platform.com

I'm starting with API Platform and I'm using the example entity "Foo":

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * Foo
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="foo")
 * @ApiResource
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Foo
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="bar", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $bar;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;


}
```

I succesfully see the new Entity in dashboard (See image):

[API Platform Dhasboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQUj0.png)

And I had the following error when I try to get all Foo collection:

```
curl -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:8000/foos" -H "accept: application/json"

    {
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10",
  "title": "An error occurred",
  "detail": "Unable to generate an IRI for the item of type \"AppBundle\\Entity\\Foo\"",
  "trace": [
    {
      "namespace": "",
      "short_class": "",
      "class": "",
      "type": "",
      "function": "",
      "file": "/home/xxxx/api/vendor/api-platform/core/src/Bridge/Symfony/Routing/IriConverter.php",
      "line": 107,
      "args": []
    },
```

I tried different formats and check the the routes too:

```
 julian@js:~/xxxxx/api$ ./bin/console debug:router
 ------------------------------- -------- -------- ------ ----------------------------------- 
  Name                            Method   Scheme   Host   Path                               
 ------------------------------- -------- -------- ------ ----------------------------------- 
  _wdt                            ANY      ANY      ANY    /_wdt/{token}                      
  _profiler_home                  ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/                        
  _profiler_search                ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search                  
  _profiler_search_bar            ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search_bar              
  _profiler_phpinfo               ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/phpinfo                 
  _profiler_search_results        ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/search/results  
  _profiler_open_file             ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/open                    
  _profiler                       ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}                 
  _profiler_router                ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/router          
  _profiler_exception             ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception       
  _profiler_exception_css         ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception.css   
  _twig_error_test                ANY      ANY      ANY    /_error/{code}.{_format}           
  api_entrypoint                  ANY      ANY      ANY    /{index}.{_format}                 
  api_doc                         ANY      ANY      ANY    /docs.{_format}                    
  api_jsonld_context              ANY      ANY      ANY    /contexts/{shortName}.{_format}            
  api_foos_get_collection         GET      ANY      ANY    /foos.{_format}                    
  api_foos_post_collection        POST     ANY      ANY    /foos.{_format}                    
  api_foos_get_item               GET      ANY      ANY    /foos/{id}.{_format}               
  api_foos_put_item               PUT      ANY      ANY    /foos/{id}.{_format}               
  api_foos_delete_item            DELETE   ANY      ANY    /foos/{id}.{_format}               

 ------------------------------- -------- -------- ------ -----------------------------------
```

It's possible what I need some special library in my server? What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you install it? I use their example installation through composer `composer create-project api-platform/api-platform bookshop-api`  https://api-platform.com/docs/distribution and it worked like a charm for me.

Comment: Yes, now the Foo Entity example work, but the reversed Tour entity not... Im thinking that some relations can be breaking stuffs.

Comment: Can you elaborate what is reversed Tour entity please ?

Comment: Yes, I build an entity parting from a existing MySQL table (reverse engineering) with the command bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AppBundle annotation This command build a entity file (Tours) with only private properties (no geters or seters), so I generate geters and seters with command bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle:Tours

Comment: I can confirm that it was a problem with the identifiers... and the clear of cache  after adding the getId() method.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're missing a getter for your id

```
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}
```

Comment: I created a full set of geters and seters running: bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle:Tours and the problem persist... In Foo table work, but not in this Entity. Maybe some relation 1:n n:n?

Comment: I can confirm that it is a problem with the identifiers... But cannot solve the problem...

Comment: Solved cleaning cache! Thanks so much!

Comment: Imagine that you are receiving data fromf an AP, so you dont have an entity or persisted id ?

Comment: @famas23 What do you mean by "AP"?

Comment: "API" Application interface, sorry, in fact when you are receiving data from an external api, then you deserialize that data into new DTO objects that does not represent any relation with the current database. In that case  apiplatform serializerListner, gonna try to generate IRI for ITem, and then you gonna get "Unable to generate an IRI for the item" Exception, cause the the getItem() method is supposed to return an Entity

Answer (score 1):

I met this issue during the implementation of "API Platform  + ElasticSearch".

Debugged the exception I found more clearer explanation:
"**Not able to retrieve
identifiers. Unable to generate an IRI for the item of type "App\Entity\...**"

In my case entity didn't have a **setId()** method.

```
public function setId(int $id): void
{
    $this->id = $id;
}
```

It has helped me.

Answer (score 0):

For future visitors:

You'll get this error allways if you disable json-ld format. Check your configuration file ./config/packages/api_platform.yaml:

```
formats:
        json:     ['application/json']
        jsonld:   ['application/ld+json']
        jsonapi:  ['application/vnd.api+json']
        html:     ['text/html']
        csv:      ['text/csv']
```

This error can be launched for several reasons. Other one happens when you declare an entity without ORM and you **forgot declare its ItemDataProvider**

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer as it may help other people, I had a typo in my `uriTemplate` parameter, and used `{format}` instead of `{_format}` which caused the `$this->router->generate` to fail in `vendor/api-platform/core/src/Symfony/Routing/IriConverter.php`.

```
#[ApiResource(
    uriTemplate: '/users/{user_id}/subresource.{_format}',
```

To debug this, comment the try/catch in the `IriConverter.php` class to see the exact error.

Answer (score 0):

I was passing for a similar problem, and I was having a big difficulty to find a solution.

Just to help someone that couldn't find some answer, I suggest going deeper and put some debug/dump inside the IriConverter class to see what is really happening.

I discovered that my main class was ok, but another a relation/linked class had a problem. So sometimes could be in another place but with the same error.

Answer (score -3):

Remove your existing entity and create new model with bin/console make:entity has worked for me !