# api-platform | Is there a way to disable the WriteListener on a specific operation or route?

Tags: php, api-platform.com

So because of [api-platform.com Unable to generate an IRI for the item of type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51136184/api-platform-com-unable-to-generate-an-iri-for-the-item-of-type) I tried using a different approach and declare custom operations on my user entity for login, registration and reset (since I stil want custom business logics for them). So the initial set-up of that in api-platform is rather easy. I added the following code to my user entity

```
 *      collectionOperations={
 *          "register"={"route_name"="user_register","normalization_context"={"groups"={"registerRead"}},"denormalization_context"={"groups"={"registerWrite"}}},
 *          "reset"={"route_name"="user_reset","normalization_context"={"groups"={"resetRead"}},"denormalization_context"={"groups"={"resetWrite"}}},
 *          "login"={"route_name"="user_login","normalization_context"={"groups"={"loginRead"}},"denormalization_context"={"groups"={"loginWrite"}}},
 *          "token"={"route_name"="user_token","normalization_context"={"groups"={"tokenRead"}},"denormalization_context"={"groups"={"token"}}}
 *      },
```

And then added the appropriate actions to the user controller.

```
/**
 * @Route(
 *     name="user_login",
 *     path="api/user/login",
 *     methods={"POST"},
 *     defaults={
 *         "_api_resource_class"=User::class,
 *         "_api_collection_operation_name"="login",
 *         "_api_receive"=false
 *     }
 * )
 */
public function loginAction(User $data): User {

    ///$this->userService->login($data);

    return $data;
}

/**
 * @Route(
 *     name="user_register",
 *     path="api/user/register",
 *     methods={"POST"},
 *     defaults={
 *         "_api_resource_class"=User::class,
 *         "_api_collection_operation_name"="register",
 *         "_api_receive"=false
 *     }
 * )
 */
public function registerAction(User $data): User {

    ///$this->userService->register($data);

    return $data;
}

/**
 * @Route(
 *     name="user_reset",
 *     path="api/user/reset",
 *     methods={"POST"},
 *     defaults={
 *         "_api_resource_class"=User::class,
 *         "_api_collection_operation_name"="reset",
 *         "_api_receive"=false
 *     }
 * )
 */
public function resetAction(User $data): User {

    //$this->userService->reset($data);

    return $data;
}

/**
 * @Route(
 *     name="user_token",
 *     path="api/user/token",
 *     methods={"POST"},
 *     defaults={
 *         "_api_resource_class"=User::class,
 *         "_api_collection_operation_name"="token",
 *         "_api_receive"=false
 *     }
 * )
 */
public function tokenAction(User $data): User {

    //$this->userService->reset($data);

    return $data;
}
```

So far al fine, however..... because we are using a post operation here and the user is a doctrine ORM entity the api-platform bundle atomically adds the post to the database. But I don’t want that, I want it to pass the entity on to the controller who then uses a service to do business logics.  And determine if and how the post should be processed.

Now I went over the documentation and the problem seems to be that the WriteListener always triggers there were other triggers (e.g. ReadListener, DeserializeListener and ValidateListener) can be disabled trough the _api_receive parameter.

So that leaves the question is there a way to disable the  WriteListener on a specific operation or route?

Kind Regards,
Ruben van der Linde

Comment: And yes I tried using a non ORM enity, but that keeps giving me an IRI error.

Answer (score 0):

You can return an instance of HttpFoundation's `Response` instead of `$data`. Then no listener registered on `kernel.view` will be called.

But introducing a listener similar to `api_receive` for the write listener is a good idea. Would you mind opening a Pull Request?

Edit: I've opened a Pull Request to introduce this new flag: https://github.com/api-platform/core/pull/2072

Comment: Do we know what the current alternative this is?